# How to Add ComboBox inside ListView On Mouse Double Click Event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add ComboBox inside ListView on mouse double click event. On each double click, a new ComboBox should be added on the next row.

I tried it with the code below, but its not working.

```
 private void form_DblClick(object sender, form_DblClickEvent e)
 {
      ComboBox c;
      this.Controls.Add(c = new ComboBox());
      c.Items.Add("Input");
      c.Items.Add("Delay");
      c.Items.Add("Message");
      c.Items.Add("comment");
      listView1.Controls.Add(c);
 }
```

can any one help me in solving this problem..

Answer (score 0):

You should use ComboboxItem

```
ComboBox c;
ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
item.Text = "Input";
item.Value = value;
c.Items.Add(item)
ComboboxItem item1 = new ComboboxItem();
item1.Text = "Delay";
item1.Value = value;
c.Items.Add(item1)
//........
```

Comment: no actually i want to add combobox will all of the above elements  in one combobox..when i double click it again..in next line another combobox will be added with all elements ....